# How to make Scrollview scrolling ios swift 4

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

I am beginner to ios development(i am using "Swift 4") and i am currently stuck in a problem with UIscrollview.
In My case i have two scrollviews 
  1. In Xib
  2. In viewController
In viewController my design hierarchy is as Below

---

| first View . |

---

| Second View .|

---

|              | 
|              | 
|              | 
|   Xib View   | 
|              | 
|              | 
|              |

---

Now when i scroll the scrollview in the xib scrolls but my ViewController ScrollView is not scrolling
What i want to do is when User Scrolls
The scrollview of the main view controlller should scroll and stops when the "First view" "Hides". then my xib's Scrollview should start..

Comment: I am not sure about your problem, please elaborate

Comment: https://mir-cdn.behance.net/v1/rendition/project_modules/max_1200/bb520555685471.59918d3d32a87.gif

Comment: the first image in the link 
they are using listview but instead of that list i have a xib

Comment: Your question is still not clear

Comment: tell me which part needs to be clear??

Comment: your complete Question! needs to be clear

Comment: that sounds complicated